# Managing concurrent docker-compose up commands

Tags: docker

I'm using docker with a testing library and set the library up to start the container with `docker compose up` by simply executing the command. Unfortunately in some cases the library will execute the command twice concurrently, causing duplicate network/container errors since both `compose up` commands are running at the same time.

What would be a good way to force only one command to run and avoid the errors? I'm thinking of parsing `docker compose ls` before executing the command, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Maybe moving the command to a shell script, executing that, and checking for its name in the processes?

Comment: lock with `flock`

Comment: Can this work if different processes execute the script? I don't know how the library is executing the command but it could be from different processes.

Comment: See `man flock`. Locks are on file. You could flock on docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Which test library exactly are you using?  Is there any sort of "before all" hook you could use?  Do you _need_ to dynamically containers as part of this particular test process?

Comment: @DavidMaze It's vitest. I set up a custom environment that starts the containers in the environment setup. I've only written one test file at this point and noticed that vitest runs multiple processes when updating snapshots in watch mode (really specific but does expose the issue). I assume the issue would also occur with multiple tests since they're ran in parallel.

Comment: I see that Vitest has a global setup option which runs, so I'll try that out with a separate config.